# ASP.NET Request.Files empty with bad connection only

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a file upload page allowing to upload multiple documents.

When I use it with a reasonably good connection, it works fine : for each individual file, my controller action is called and `Request.Files` does contain one single file.

However, when I simulate a bad connection using the developer tools (GPRS speed), when my controller action is called, `Request.Files` is empty.

I also tried with a medium connection (3G), and I got a mix of both : two files were successfuly uploaded and I did have one file in `Request.Files` for each of them, and the other two failed with `Request.Files` being empty.

Is this a normal behaviour ? What I would like to know is if there is something wrong in my code, or if I'm wasting my time trying to fix something that is not avoidable.

All the questions I saw about this issue indicate that I should specify `multipart/form-data` for the `enctype` attribute of the form, but this  is not a solution to my issue since it works just fine with a good connection.

### Edit

@Gunnarhawk, this is how I perform the AJAX call :

```
return $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetUploadedFileList", "Process", new { claimId = @claimId })',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    data: dataJson, // Object as JSON text
    processData: false,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        // Stuff...
    },
    error: function () {
        // Stuff...
    }
});
```

Comment: What status code is the request getting when it does not go through, could it be timing out? Also, you say it may be a problem with your code. Can you post it?

Comment: @Gunnarhawk Well it seems like in does not return any code. The developer tools don't indicate any code, as opposed to 200 for thosethat worked, despite the fact that the query does have a duration and begin/end times. I can't post my whole code unfortunately, cause it's a credit card related website, but I guess I can post a part of the JS since it's visible from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to increase the execution timeout or max request length (to allow larger file uploads and for the page to run longer).

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="byte size limit" executionTimeout="timeout in seconds" />
```

See the [docs on maxRequestLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.8)

> The maximum request size in kilobytes. The default size is 4096 KB (4 MB).

And the [docs on executionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8)

> A TimeSpan value that indicates the allowed execution time for the request.

I believe the time for executionTimeout is in seconds, so if you set it to 300, that is 5 minutes.

Doing this can allow a public application to be attacked by a malicious user, by trying to upload really large files, so be aware.

You can use the `<location href="path">` element to scope the changes to a specific page in your application.  See more on location [in the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/application-directory-configuration#:%7E:text=Summary-,The%20Web.,is%20specific%20to%20the%20application).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I beleive it has nothing to do with the length since it works when using a good connection. Regarding the timeout, jQuery expects milliseconds, so I tried with 120000 (2 minutes) and I got the same issue.